Calculate current market cap from raydium pool
I use the Raydium SDK to retrieve Pool Information for a given token address.
I have read that you calculate the price by this formula:
price=solInPool / tokensInPool
And the market cap would then be:
marketCap = price * totalSupply
But the results seem to be wrong when I use mintAmountA for solInPool and mintAmountB for tokensInPool from this raydium SDK response:
{
  "count": 1,
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "Standard",
      "programId": "675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8",
      "id": "3LamnqZVFRXdtAuJjVdVhaiLBWJRCqnW4m67egHv7mGA",
      "mintA": {
        "chainId": 101,
        "address": "So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",
        "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
        "logoURI": "https://img-v1.raydium.io/icon/So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112.png",
        "symbol": "WSOL",
        "name": "Wrapped SOL",
        "decimals": 9,
        "tags": [],
        "extensions": {}
      },
      "mintB": {
        "chainId": 101,
        "address": "662wQT1buc7KeXUat2JHb6DtFzmxdbFNo6c3i7PMpump",
        "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
        "logoURI": "https://img-v1.raydium.io/icon/662wQT1buc7KeXUat2JHb6DtFzmxdbFNo6c3i7PMpump.png",
        "symbol": "SINISTER",
        "name": "sinister",
        "decimals": 6,
        "tags": [],
        "extensions": {}
      },
      "price": 43678601.10592065,
      "mintAmountA": 20.082643884,
      "mintAmountB": 877181791.361493,
      "feeRate": 0.0025,
      "openTime": "0",
      "tvl": 5274.22,
      "day": {
        "volume": 75144.21193050311,
        "volumeQuote": 4621778507.121746,
        "volumeFee": 187.86052982625452,
        "apr": 1300.08,
        "feeApr": 1300.08,
        "priceMin": 1696003.4365428572,
        "priceMax": 43800532.78431799,
        "rewardApr": []
      },
      "week": {
        "volume": 209358.4385045331,
        "volumeQuote": 11033335125.21151,
        "volumeFee": 523.3960962613232,
        "apr": 297.71,
        "feeApr": 297.71,
        "priceMin": 1696003.4365428572,
        "priceMax": 43800532.78431799,
        "rewardApr": []
      },
      "month": {
        "volume": 209358.4385045331,
        "volumeQuote": 11033335125.21151,
        "volumeFee": 523.3960962613232,
        "apr": 119.08,
        "feeApr": 119.08,
        "priceMin": 1696003.4365428572,
        "priceMax": 43800532.78431799,
        "rewardApr": []
      },
      "pooltype": [
        "OpenBookMarket"
      ],
      "rewardDefaultInfos": [],
      "farmUpcomingCount": 0,
      "farmOngoingCount": 0,
      "farmFinishedCount": 0,
      "marketId": "8DAadF37acSnxFZgTD8pyvnzJMd3YrKHZsRcZPpkePVu",
      "lpMint": {
        "chainId": 101,
        "address": "5XmMP1U7iBdd1swMW8MMS7SW9RNfgnxqWyXfE1aZ5G9P",
        "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
        "logoURI": "",
        "symbol": "",
        "name": "",
        "decimals": 9,
        "tags": [],
        "extensions": {}
      },
      "lpPrice": 1.304518109644378,
      "lpAmount": 4043.044543939,
      "burnPercent": 100
    }
  ],
  "hasNextPage": false
}

What's the correct way of doing it? I am sure it's an error in my assumption.

It looks like you might be mixing things up a bit. Here’s how you can get it right:
Identify the SOL token:
For this pool, Wrapped SOL (WSOL) is the SOL token. You should use mintAmountA for solInPool because it’s linked to mintA.
Identify the other token:
The other token is SINISTER. So, use mintAmountB for tokensInPool.
Calculating the price:
Use this formula: price = solInPool / tokensInPool
So, with mintAmountA for SOL and mintAmountB for the token, it’ll be: price = 20.082643884 / 877181791.361493 ≈ 2.29 × 10^-8 SOL
Finding the market cap:
To get the market cap, just multiply the price by the totalSupply of SINISTER. You’ll need to get totalSupply from somewhere else since it’s not in the pool data.
This should give you a more accurate result. Make sure you’re using mintAmountA for SOL and mintAmountB for the other token.
Hope this clears things up!

Sorry, i got the variable names wrong. I already use the variables you suggested. mintAmountA/mintAmountB, but the results seem to be not correct. I would assume i get roughly the same number as on descreener when i multiply market cap in sol with the current solana price in usd. But the results are far off.
